# Are there any web controls in FusionCharts?

Tags: fusioncharts

I checked their website and apart from the gallery I couldn't find anything prosper.

For example, Google has Control Wrappers. What are the controls I can adhere to FusionCharts or would I have to go with third-party controls or build my own custom Control Wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, FusionCharts is purely a charting outsource component they only provide the charts- rendered from 2 data formats- XML/JSON provided to it.

As of now, they don't provide any **Web Controls**.
I suggest you to create the same using Coding and Integrate the chart there.
Hope ths helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using FusionCharts, updating or changing the data passed to the chart will result in re-rendering of the chart, unlike with Google Charts' ControlWrapper. They serve different purposes, and there are some significant differences to consider. 
Do take a look at http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-charting-comparison/ to understand the various options for charting.